# Redirect to default action in Struts 2

Tags: redirect, struts2

I have an action with an empty string for name defined in the root namespace, and I want to redirect to that action from another action if a certain result is found, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the default action

```
<action name="" class="com.example.actions.HomeAction">
    <result name="success" type="freemarker">freemarker/home.ftl</result>
</action>
```

And I'm defining the redirect in the global-results for the package:

```
<global-results>
    <result name="sendToRouting" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName"></param>
        <param name="namespace">/</param>
    </result>
</global-results>
```

I've tried taking out the actionName parameter, but that doesn't work.  If I put a name in for the HomeAction and reference it by name in the global-results it works, so I'm assuming the problem is lack of action name for the redirect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Change type to type="redirect-action"

Comment: I'm using struts 2.1.6, I read that redirect-action was switched to redirectAction in a previous version.

Comment: Just curious, what could be a "good" reason to not just give the action a name? for example, "default" or something? I don't see any advantage of using an action with no name.

Comment: Maybe the OP is have the same issue as mine: clients want to access with `host/myApp/admin`, without any action name behind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is use `<default-action-ref />`:

```
<package name="home" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <default-action-ref name="home" />

    <action name="home" class="com.example.actions.HomeAction">
        <result name="success" type="freemarker">freemarker/home.ftl</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

Sorry...misread the question:

Try changing `type="redirectAction"` to `type="redirect"`, I'm fairly sure that redirectAction is now redirect.

Comment: No, `redirect` is for URLs, while `redirectAction` allows you to reference action names directly.

Answer (score 3):

Were you getting a NullPointerException because the actionName parameter is blank? I hacked around this by providing a string which *evaluates* to an empty string:

```
<param name="actionName">${}</param>
```

Still looking for a more "correct" solution though...

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting work around.  I'll have to give that a try as well